# Flutter/Dart compiler in IntelliJ IDea throwing `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'file' was called on null.`

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, dart

When trying to compile/run my Flutter project in IntelliJ IDEA I get this error (with no hint what part of my code it relates to).  Any ideas please?  Thanks!!

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'file' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: file
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      ProgramCompiler.visitAssertStatement (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3468:59)
#2      ProgramCompiler._initializeFields (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1521:20)
#3      ProgramCompiler._emitConstructorBody (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1392:14)
#4      ProgramCompiler._emitConstructor.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1355:19)
#5      ProgramCompiler._superDisallowed (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3122:24)
#6      ProgramCompiler._emitConstructor.<anonymous closure> (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1354:15)
#7      ProgramCompiler._withLetScope (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:2096:25)
#8      ProgramCompiler._withCurrentFunction (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3112:18)
#9      ProgramCompiler._emitConstructor (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1352:16)
#10     ProgramCompiler._defineConstructors (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:972:38)
#11     ProgramCompiler._emitClassDeclaration (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:567:19)
#12     ProgramCompiler._emitClass (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:510:21)
#13     List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:282:8)
#14     ProgramCompiler._emitLibrary (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:459:23)
#15     List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:282:8)
#16     ProgramCompiler.emitModule (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:345:15)
#17     JavaScriptBundler.compile (package:frontend_server/src/javascript_bundle.dart:133:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
....
Finished with error: the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Failed to compile application.
```

Comment: Well, copying all the .dart files to a fresh project solve it, so that's the workaround :-)

Comment: See also: https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1845, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689534/another-exception-was-thrown-nosuchmethoderror-the-getter-latitude-was-calle